# Is it possible to do calculus on any field with a topology?

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, field-theory

I'll try to make my point clear: when we consider the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ we can do calculus there because we have properties of a field and in the same time we have a topology to define limits. So, we have a metric given by the norm and so we can construct a basis for a topology using this metric and everything works fine. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, then we can define algebraic functions like $f : \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(z)=z^k$ and the properties of the field together with the definition of limit implies that we can define a derivative $f'(z)=kz^{k-1}$.

Integration seems more complicated and requiring more structure because we integrate differential forms, so we must be able to talk about them. My question is: if $F$ is any field and if $\tau$ is a topology on $F$, can we define a differential calculus exactly as we do with $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$? My thought was that the only true requirement was that the we need a metric and that $(F,d)$ should be complete, but I can be totally wrong.

Is just possible to do differential calculus like we do with $\mathbb{C}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ in any field endowed with a metric or this just works in those two specific fields?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I think you'd need that $(F,\,\tau)$ is a topological field (the field operations are continuous), and that $F$ is at least not discrete to get anything useful.

Comment: You might be interested in the abstract concept of a derivation, which is one way of generalising differentiation - it doesn't immediately meet your case, but it applies in contexts where a definition in terms of limits does not work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(abstract_algebra)

Comment: You might also be interested in the example of the $p$-adic numbers, which is another example of a complete metric field. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_differentiable

Comment: I not sure that I agree with the notion that integration requires more structure than differentiation.  Integration requires only some kind of measure space.  Differentiation would seem to require more, i.e. being a Frechet space.

Comment: A construction of a calculus is possible onto many topological objects with some additional structure. For instance on smooth manifolds in differential geometry, on Banach spaces in functional analysis, on compact topological groups in topological algebra. Also there are $p$-adic numbers, and, probably, (local) Lie groups.

Comment: Divided power structures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_power_structure and Goodwillie calculus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_functors may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Every locally compact group has a Haar measure (unique up to a scalar). This provides a nice theory of integration. Locally compactness is also necessary for this, I think.

A theory of derivatives might not exist, e.g. for $\mathbb{Q}_p$ smoothness is a trivial concept (=locally constant).

Some special functions with an integral representation as the $\Gamma$-function make sense e.g. for $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

The radius of convergence of power series behaves weird for $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as well. I think that the exponential function has finite radius of convergence.

Btw, all locally compact, non-discrete fields have been classified. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field

- finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$
- the field of formal Laurent series $F_q((T))$ over a finite field $F_q$
- $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$

They all are equiped with an absolute value.

Comment: +1. But won't using the Haar measure (or any measure?) force us to integrate real (or complex) valued functions only. Also, forming the limit of any kind of sums of an increasing number of smaller and smaller $p$-adic numbers is kinda pointless, because the valuation is non-archimedean. Forming Riemann-Darboux style upper and lower sums also require an ordering pointing also in the direction of integrals being real valued (or possibly a Banach space)

Comment: As far as I know $\mathbb{Q}_p$-valued measures do not exist for example. There are motivic measures and $p$-adic L-functions, but I do not know much about them.